# Return value from wrapper inside decorator

Tags: python, return, wrapper, decorator

I have defined the following decorator:

```
def _send(code):
    def wrapper(func):
        def wrapperIn(*args, **kwargs):
            # Do stuff
            return value
        return wrapperIn
    return wrapper
```

and the following function that is being decorated with it:

```
@_send(0)
def _getServerResponse(ID):
    pass
```

I need to be "value" in the decorator the returned variable when _getServerResponse is called, but even though I try I only achieve to return "None" as if the value would've been lost somewhere between the wrappers calls.

Is there a possible way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to return the `code` variable?

Comment: What do you expect to be returned? Your decorated function return nothing...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your

```
# Do stuff
```

looks like the following lines:

```
value = func(*args, **kwargs)
return value
```

Since your wrapped function returns a None, you are getting None :). This is just assumption, to give you the 100% correct answer I do need more lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your function's actually returning something and that the `wrapperIn` function is returning that value.

if you're still confused, step into the code in `wrapperIn` and take a look.